# malloc(): corrupted top size when overloading + operator in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, constructor, operator-overloading, memory-corruption

I'm trying to write a template class function for doing some basic operations with matrices. I have been struggling (a lot, for almost a week ) with memory issues, since it seems like every time i call my constructor class it corrupts the object. I am also suspecting that something is wrong when I define the overload function for the + operator, the most strange thing is that my code works fine with 2x2 matrices but nothing more than that!

I would appreciate if someone has any idea of which could be the problem!
Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

template<class TypeData>
class Matrix{

    private: 
    int Nrows , Ncols;
    TypeData *Array_Matrix;

    public:
    /*Constructors---------*/
    Matrix(){
        Nrows = 0;
        Ncols = 0;
        Array_Matrix = nullptr;
    }
    /*Constructor with 2 parameters:*/
    Matrix(int _Nrows , int _Ncols){
        this -> Nrows = _Nrows;
        this -> Ncols = _Ncols;
        Array_Matrix = new TypeData [Nrows * Ncols];
        for(int i = 0 ; i<Nrows * Ncols ; i++){Array_Matrix[i] = 0.0;}
    }
    /*Copy constructor:*/
    Matrix ( const Matrix &_M){
        this -> Nrows = _M.Nrows ; 
        this -> Ncols = _M.Ncols;
        Array_Matrix = new TypeData [Nrows * Ncols];
        for(int i = 0 ; i<Nrows * Ncols ; i++){*(Array_Matrix + i) = *(_M.Array_Matrix + i);}
    }

    void Set_Value(int row , int col , TypeData value){
        *(Array_Matrix  + Ncols*row + col) = value;}
    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    TypeData Get_Pos_Value(int row , int col){
        if(row >= Nrows || col >= Ncols){throw std::invalid_argument( "Error!, index out of bounds!" );}
        else{return *(Array_Matrix + Ncols*row + col) ;}}

    TypeData *Get_Array(){ /*Method for returning a pointer to the "matrix"*/
        return Array_Matrix;};

    int Get_Nrows(){
        return Nrows;}

    int Get_Ncols(){
        return Ncols;}

    void Print_Matrix(){
        for (int i = 0 ; i<Nrows ; i++){
            cout<<endl;
            for (int j = 0 ; j<Ncols ; j++){
                cout<<*(Array_Matrix + Ncols*i + j)<<" ";}}cout<<endl;}

    /*Operator overloading --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    Matrix operator = (const Matrix &Matrix_object){

        delete [] Array_Matrix;
        this -> Nrows = Matrix_object.Nrows;
        this -> Ncols = Matrix_object.Ncols;
        Array_Matrix = new TypeData [Nrows * Ncols];

        for (int i = 0 ; i<Nrows*Ncols ; i++){Array_Matrix [i] = Matrix_object.Array_Matrix[i];}

        return *this;
    }

    Matrix operator + (const Matrix &Matrix_object)const{

        if(Matrix_object.Nrows != Nrows || Matrix_object.Ncols != Ncols)
        {throw std::invalid_argument("Different siex matrices cant be added!" );}

        
        Matrix <TypeData> Temp(0,0); Temp.Nrows = Nrows ; Temp.Ncols = Ncols;
        for(int i = 0 ; i<Nrows*Ncols; i++){
                //Temp.Array_Matrix[i] = Array_Matrix[i] + Matrix_object.Array_Matrix[i];
                *(Temp.Array_Matrix +i) = *(Array_Matrix +i) + *(Matrix_object.Array_Matrix + i);} 
                return Temp;}

   Matrix operator - (const Matrix &Matrix_object)const{

        if(Matrix_object.Nrows != Nrows || Matrix_object.Ncols != Ncols)
        {throw std::invalid_argument("Different size matrices can be substracted!" );}

        Matrix <TypeData> Temp(0,0); Temp.Nrows = Nrows ; Temp.Ncols = Ncols;
        for(int i = 0 ; i<Nrows*Ncols; i++){
                //Temp.Array_Matrix[i] = Array_Matrix[i] - Matrix_object.Array_Matrix[i];
                *(Temp.Array_Matrix +i) = *(Array_Matrix +i) - *(Matrix_object.Array_Matrix + i);}

        return Temp;}

    Matrix operator += (const TypeData num){

        Matrix <TypeData> Temp(0,0); Temp.Nrows = Nrows ; Temp.Ncols = Ncols;
            for(int i = 0 ; i<Nrows*Ncols; i++){
                    Temp.Array_Matrix[i] =  Array_Matrix[i]  + num ;} return Temp;}

    Matrix operator -= (const TypeData num){

        Matrix <TypeData> Temp(0,0); Temp.Nrows = Nrows ; Temp.Ncols = Ncols;
            for(int i = 0 ; i<Nrows*Ncols; i++){
                    Temp.Array_Matrix[i] =  Array_Matrix[i]- num ;} return Temp;}

   ~Matrix(){ delete[] Array_Matrix;}
   };
```

Main

```
int main(){
    int r1 , c1; cout<<"Matrix1: Enter Number of rows and columns  "; cin>>r1>>c1;
    Matrix <float> My_Matrix(r1 , c1);

    for (int i = 0 ; i<My_Matrix.Get_Nrows() ; i++){
            for (int j = 0 ; j<My_Matrix.Get_Ncols(); j++){
                float value; cout<<"Type the value at: ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] position  "; cin>>value;
                My_Matrix.Set_Value(i , j , value);}}


    int r2 , c2; cout<<"Matrix2: Enter Number of rows and columns   "<<endl; cin>>r2>>c2;
    Matrix <float> My_Matrix2(r2,c2);

    for (int i = 0 ; i<My_Matrix2.Get_Nrows() ; i++){
            for (int j = 0 ; j<My_Matrix2.Get_Ncols(); j++){
                float value; cout<<"Type the value at: ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] position  "; cin>>value;
                My_Matrix2.Set_Value(i , j , value);}}


  
    auto My_Matrix3 = My_Matrix + My_Matrix2;
    cout<<"Add:    "<<endl;
    My_Matrix3.Print_Matrix();
    cout<<endl;
    
    cout<<"Testing substraction:    "<<endl;
    auto My_Matrix4 = My_Matrix - My_Matrix2;
    cout<<"Substraction is:  "<<endl;
    My_Matrix4.Print_Matrix();
    cout<<endl; 

    cout<<"Testing = operator:  "<<endl;
    My_Matrix4 = My_Matrix3;
    cout<<"Substraction matriz is now:  "<<endl;
    My_Matrix4.Print_Matrix();
    cout<<endl<<"as the Add matrix! "<<endl;

    cout<<"Testing +=:"<<endl;
    int num ; cout<<"Please enter an integer number:  ";cin>>num;
    (My_Matrix4 += num).Print_Matrix();
    return 0;}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector`, rather than trying to manage the memory yourself.

Comment: well... is with self-learning/ educational proporuses

Comment: `Matrix <TypeData> Temp(0,0); Temp.Nrows = Nrows ; Temp.Ncols = Ncols;` Your `Temp` has an array of length 0. The following loop tries to write to elements which don't exist in that array.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Nrows`, `_Ncols`, `_M`) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: If you are running on Linux, you can use Valgrind tool which will show you exactly where your program is corrupting the memory.

Comment: @tkausl Thank you!, I didnt realized !

Comment: @JFCastello `Matrix operator += (const TypeData num)` -- This should be returning a reference to the current `Matrix`, not a brand new `Matrix`.  Same thing with `-=`.  This should be: `Matrix& operator += (const TypeData num) { ... return *this; }`.

Comment: `Matrix operator = (const Matrix &Matrix_object)` -- This is also wrong, as it should be returning a reference to the current object.  And in all of that, this is a simple function:  `Matrix& operator = (Matrix Matrix_object) { std::swap(Matrix_object.Nrows , Nrows); std::swap(Matrix_object.Ncols, Ncols); std::swap(Matrix_object.Array_Matrix, Array_Matrix); return *this;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Matrix <TypeData> Temp(0,0);
```

Good news: you created a `Matrix` with 0 rows, 0 columns, and 0 values total.

```
                              Temp.Nrows = Nrows ; Temp.Ncols = Ncols;
```

Bad news: the number of rows and columns gets clobbered to something else, then:

```
        for(int i = 0 ; i<Nrows*Ncols; i++){
                //Temp.Array_Matrix[i] = Array_Matrix[i] + Matrix_object.Array_Matrix[i];
                *(Temp.Array_Matrix +i) = *(Array_Matrix +i) + *(Matrix_object.Array_Matrix + i);} 
                return Temp;}
```

... the code procedes on the assumption that the `Temp.Array_Matrix` will have `Nrows*Ncols` values. Of course, it doesn't. Hence the memory corruption.

The same bug occurs multiple times in the shown code.

Comment: I get it... but when i remove the first constructor from the code , it keeps failing with the same error.

Comment: Do something like `Matrix <TypeData> Temp(Nrows, Ncols)`. `Temp.Nrows` and `Temp.Ncols` will be appropriately set, but this time `Array_Matrix` will be allocated to the correct size. Then you can cut out the line `Temp.Nrows = Nrows ; Temp.Ncols = Ncols;` because that's already done in the constructor

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the constructor itself. The issue is not in the constructor.